# jquery-file-upload: handle multiple uploads but create photo object before fileupload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, jquery-file-upload

I am using rails and jquery-file-upload to handle multiple photo uploads from browser to server. I had an example setup working, but the thing is that I would like to create a photo object on the server first for each photo before sending the photo itself (I want users to be able to set attributes on the photo while the upload is still in progress so I need an id on the server for that).

Therefore I implemented the jquery-file-upload add event to first send an AJAX request to the server and execute its javascript response which includes a new_photo_id and a template placeholder called add_to_dom to display on the client. Since I don't yet have the photo id when the form is created, I need to update the url that jquery-file-upload uses to send the photo to include the id which is possible only after the photo object creation succeeded.

For a single file this approach works well, but for multiple files I see only one AJAX create request coming in, and it tries to upload all files with the same new_photo_id. Initially I thought that the problem lies with the global scope of the new_photo_id variable (this might still be an issue), but as said I actually see only one ajax create request coming in.

Also worthwhile to mention is that I was initially following the railscast about jquery-file-upload where he uses the method of sending files on by one instead of in an array. Indeed I see that the browser passes multiple file data objects to the server that contain a files array[1] with the info for each file (as well as an originalfiles array with metadata).

The form looks something like this:

```
<form action="/photos" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileupload" method="post">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />
  <input id="photo_image" multiple="multiple" name="photo[image]" type="file" />
</form>
```

This is the code that handles the jquery-file-upload on the client side:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: "script",
    add: function(e, data) {
      // first create new photo object
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/photos',
        dataType: "script"
      }).success(function() {
         // add new photo row to dom
         $('#photos').append(add_to_dom);

         // change file upload url to reflect newly created photo object
         data.url='/photos/'+new_photo_id;

         // submit photo
         return data.submit();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The JS response from the server that is executed by jquery is created by rails and along the lines of:

```
new_photo_id=<%= @photo.id %>;
add_to_dom='<%= j(render partial: "photos/photo", object: @photo) %>';
```

What am I missing??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: OK I forgot to mention that I was checking with Chrome which displays the behavior mentioned above. In Firefox it works just fine, I see both AJAX create requests coming in and when selecting multiple images they are uploaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with your code. However, it is worth noting that the fileupload module replaces the file input control each time a file is added. Since yours has an id attribute, I wonder if there is some weirdness going on there. You might try removing that attribute to see if it changes things.

Another difference between my code and yours is that I do not have an enctype attribute on my form.

I'm not very confident this will fix your problem, but your code looks okay so something is amiss.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. As mentioned in the comment I added to my original post, it turns out that in Firefox it works just fine as opposed to Chrome that I used earlier...

Answer (score 0):

OK so after reading [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14334) that suggests there might be a caching problem, I changed the route for the photo creation to GET instead of POST and this seemed to help. Not entirely sure why though, because the jquery ajax docs state that for dataType script caching is off by default. If anyone has an explanation I'll be happy too hear it :)

Comment: I am stumped, Joni. Please let us know if you figure out this mystery.